# How to pass fetch response in navigation parameters?

Tags: react-native

In my screen Search, I create a fetch which return a json as response.
I'm setting this response as parameter to navigate to Screen B.
What is the best practice to create this parameter?

I just sent the response but in the other side it's undefined!

```
fetch(this.endPoint, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: null,
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log('the result is');
                console.log(response);

                this.props.navigation.navigate("Available", {'searchResult' : response})
            })
```

```
// in screen B
render() {
        let list = this.props.navigation.getParam('searchResult');
        console.log(this.list); // returns undefined
        return (
            .....
        );
    }
```

Expected result: Receive the Json 
Actual result: Receive an undefined

Comment: `console.log(list)`, without the `this` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is basically a variable inside the `render()` method. So, you can call it directly without the instance object `this`.

```
console.log(list);
```

Also since you are using `getParam`, it is better if you call it with a default fallback value for your `list` in case it is `undefined`. For example, if `list` is supposed to be an array of values,

```
let list = this.props.navigation.getParam('searchResult', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fetch(this.endPoint, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: null,
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log('the result is');
        console.log(response);
        /* 1. Navigate to the Available route with params */
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
            searchResult: response,
        });
    })
```

And read params from Available route:

```
 const list = navigation.getParam('searchResult', 'some default value');
 console.log(list); // without this
```